# FSEEK gets the position of the last character instead of the wanted one

Tags: c, fseek

I am making a program that enables the user to edit a text file. One of the available options is "move". When selected, the program asks for a number of character to skip, and it skips them in the file, using `fseek`.

However to do that I need to ensure that the position the user tries to reach corresponds to an actual character. To do so, I have created a function that checks if the skipping is possible.

This is how I do:

1. I save the position in the file, as `pos`.
2. I use `fseek` to get the position of the last character in the file.
3. I compare this position to the position corresponding to the sum of `pos` and the number of characters that the user wants to skip.
4. Whether the result is `true` or `false`, the position in the file is always reset to its initial value, `pos`, using `fseek`.

This is my original code:

```
if (pos + nb > ftell(file))
{
    fseek(file, 0, pos);
    return (1);
}
else
{
    fseek(file, 0, pos);
    return (0);
}
```

With this code, if the initial value, `pos`, is not 0, `fseek` will not reset the position to `pos`, but to the position of the last character. (?!) I found out that replacing the order of the arguments and passing `pos` as the offset and `0` as the starting position makes it work. But I can't get why the previous code doesn't work.

I would like some help to understand better how the function `fseek` works, there are, obviously, some details that I fail to find. I found nothing about "fseek" in the GNU C reference manual...

Comment: [C11 fseek](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2) ... and the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `fseek()` wrong, try

```
fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET);
```

always read the (*documentation* or [*specification*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2)), it will save you a lot of problems.

> I found out that replacing the order of the arguments and passing pos as the offset and 0 as the starting position makes it work. But I can't get why the previous code doesn't work

Well, it's because that's the right order for the parameters, and incidentally `0` is the value of `SEEK_SET`.

Also, you need to be careful, you say *number of characters* and that is not the same as *number of bytes*, for instance in UTF-8 number of bytes for character encoding varies from one character to another. According to the `fseek()` specification, it skips `pos` bytes, not characters.

Comment: @nounoursnoir I am glad. **Just in case**: don't use magic numbers, even if `SEEK_SET` is `0` at least in *glibc* which is what you are using, and perhaps it's mandated by the standard (*I don't know*), use `SEEK_SET` instead of `0`, because no matter what it's value is you can be sure that `SEEK_SET` WILL do what it's expected to do.